# Is it possible to log Growl 1.2.2 notifications?

Tags: macos, logging, hook, growl

Essentially I want to send my phone a pushover alert when a growl happens.

To do this I am hoping to have a hook for when a growl is fired or failing that a log file I can just scan on a cron job. Then I can use either of those to send the pushover alert.

Does growl 1.2.2 have the ability to offer a hook or log it's growls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and the answer appears many places with, often the same error(*) copied.  I just set it up myself,  so here:

Decide where you want your log file.  Examples all indicate it must exist first, though I did not verify...

```
growlog="$HOME/Library/Logs/Growl.log"
touch  "$growlog"
```

check existing growl settings, before modifying:

```
defaults read com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp
```

These are the magic settings:

```
defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp "Custom log history 1" "$growlog"
defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp GrowlLogType 1 
defaults write com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp GrowlLoggingEnabled -bool YES
```

go to the growl 'paw' in the menu line and 'restart' -- after this I saw a line in the file.  Test with a command such as this from the command line:

```
growlnotify -t programName -p normal -m 'message....'
```

Besides normal notifications, growlnotify can be useful in a script to alert the user to do something, with the 'wait' and 'sticky' flags it will wait till you click it to go away:

```
growlnotify -w -s -m 'tests have finished running; click this to run again'
```